# subscriber in vue.js UI single file component

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I am attempting to implement a subscriber in vue.js using `rabbitmq-pubsub`,

however, By doing

```
var Subscriber = require('rabbitmq-pubsub').Subscriber;
```

in terminal I see

```
warning  in ./node_modules/_colors@1.0.3@colors/lib/colors.js

127:29-43 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

in browser console Is ee

```
"[WDS] Warnings while compiling."
"./node_modules/_colors@1.0.3@colors/lib/colors.js
127:29-43 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/_colors@1.0.3@colors/lib/colors.js
 @ ./node_modules/_colors@1.0.3@colors/safe.js
 @ ./node_modules/_winston@1.1.2@winston/lib/winston/config.js
 @ ./node_modules/_winston@1.1.2@winston/lib/winston.js
 @ ./node_modules/_logfilename@0.1.3@logfilename/src/logfilename.js
 @ ./node_modules/rabbitmq-pubsub/build/subscriber.js
 @ ./node_modules/rabbitmq-pubsub/build/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/SelectServices.vue
 @ ./src/components/SelectServices.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://10.9.1.147:8081 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js"
```

but when I did this :

```
var subscriberOptions = {
  exchange: 'service_deployment_exchange',
  queueName: queue,
  url: amqpl_url
};

var subscriber = new Subscriber(subscriberOptions);
function onIncomingMessage(message) {
  debug('onIncomingMessage ', message.fields);
  console.log(message);

  subscriber.ack(message);

  //subscriber.nack(message);
};
```

but when I call the below line in the mounted function in the script element of of my vue single file complonent

```
subscriber.start(onIncomingMessage)
```

I get

```
TypeError: fs.readdirSync is not a function
```

beside just the warning still showing up in console.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use api of node in browser's code. And I think rabbitmq-pubsub is a node only module.

Comment: Can you show me an implementation of subscriber for Vue. Js?

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz Sorry I know nothing about AMQP. And I notice that rabbitmq-pubsub is based on ampqlib. Maybe you can get help from [ampqlib](https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node/pull/289)